# How to know which bin-log file is captured into mysql online backup?

Tags: mysql

I am given a mysql online backup file. Hope log-bin is enabled before taking this backup and '--master-data' is not used while using mysqldump command.
Is it possible to know bin-log sequence number contained in that backup file using any mysql command ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Anyone , Welcome to answer this question. Can anyone see this question. If so how can I find your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a MySQL utility that tells you this. Don't ask me what it is. Off topic.

Comment: Thank You. I will try to find it.